# Jquery replacing text dynamically based on JSON values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have the following list of letter one for Desktop and another for mobile.

I am trying to add an href property to all the links whose inner text matches the JSON response:
and those that doesnt match JSOn response for the letters replace them with  to show they are disabled.
Based on the Alphabets Group list available in JSON, If the letters returned from JSON response doesnt not match the letters in `alphabetnav` or `alphabetnavmobile`  I want to replace and update for both a**lphabetnav and alphabetNavMobile**

Here is my code [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/ohbogqyw/3/) I am getting lot of duplicates

Example

```
<div class="alphabetnav"><a href="#A">A</a> <a href="#B">B</a> <a href="#C">C</a> <a href="#D">D</a> <a href="#E">E</a> <a href="#F">F</a> <a href="#G">G</a> <a href="#H">H</a> <a href="#I">I</a> <a href="#J">J</a> <a href="#K">K</a> <a href="#L">L</a> <a href="#M">M</a> <a href="#N">N</a> <a href="#O">O</a> <a href="#P">P</a> <a href="#Q">Q</a> <a href="#R">R</a> <a href="#S">S</a> <a href="#T">T</a> <a href="#U">U</a> <a href="#V">V</a> <a href="#W">W</a> <a href="#X">X</a> <a href="#Y">Y</a> <a href="#Z">Z</a></div>

<div class="alphabetNavMobile"><a href="#A">A</a> <a href="#B">B</a> <a href="#C">C</a> <a href="#D">D</a> <a href="#E">E</a> <a href="#F">F</a> <a href="#G">G</a> <a href="#H">H</a> <a href="#I">I</a> <a href="#J">J</a> <a href="#K">K</a> <a href="#L">L</a> <a href="#M">M</a> <a href="#N">N</a> <a href="#O">O</a> <a href="#P">P</a> <a href="#Q">Q</a> <a href="#R">R</a> <a href="#S">S</a> <a href="#T">T</a> <a href="#U">U</a> <a href="#V">V</a> <a href="#W">W</a> <a href="#X">X</a> <a href="#Y">Y</a> <a href="#Z">Z</a></div>
```

If JSON returns G F and I
only G, F and I  will have `href` and the rest of the alphabets will have `<span>`

OUTPUT

```
 <div class="alphabetnav">
    <span> A</span><span> B</span><span>C</span><span> D</span> <span> E</span> <a href="#F">F</a <a href="#G">G</a> <span> H</span>... ....
    </div>

    <div class="alphabetNavMobile">
    <span> A</span><span> B</span><span>C</span><span> D</span> <span> E</span> <a href="#F">F</a <a href="#G">G</a><span> H</span> ... ....
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate with an example, it's kind of hard to understand **exactly** what you need? Especially this sentence "*If JSON returns G F and I only G, F and I will have href and the rest of the alphabets will have*"

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding what you want to do.  Let's see if I am understanding.  You have a set of A-Z links to page anchors.  You receive data from the server with the data to display in the page, as well as the applicable letters.  You want to remove links from any letters that don't have entries?  If that's correct, please try to clarify what is, and is not, working.

Comment: @SurrealDreams thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to add an `href` property to all the links whose inner text matches the JSON response:

Well, let's say you receive your letters as an array, then you can grab all links and add an href to those whose text is in the provided letters:

```
var letters = ['G', 'F'];

$('a').each(function(idx, a) {                // grab all links, and for each of them
    var testLetter = $(a).text().trim();      // grab the inner text which should be the letter (without any trailing or leading whitespace)
    if (letters.indexOf(testLetter) !== -1) { // if the letter is in the data received from the JSON
        $(a).attr('href', '#' + testLetter);  // add the href attribute with that letter
    } else if($(a).attr('href')) {            // otherwise, if the link has an href that doesn't match any letters
        $(a).removeAttr('href');              // remove it
    }
});
```

```js
var letters = ['G', 'F'];
$('a').each(function(idx, a) {
  var testLetter = $(a).text().trim();
  if (letters.indexOf(testLetter) !== -1) {
    $(a).attr('href', '#' + testLetter);
    console.log('adding href to ' + testLetter);
  } else if ($(a).attr('href')) {
    console.log('removing href from ' + testLetter);
    $(a).removeAttr('href');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#A">A</a>
<a href="#B">B</a>
<a>C</a>
<a>D</a>
<a>E</a>
<a>F </a>
<a>G</a>
<a>H</a>
<a>I</a>
<a>J</a>
<a>K</a>
<a>L</a>
<a>M</a>
<a>N</a>
<a>O</a>
<a>P</a>
<a>Q</a>
<a>R</a>
<a>S</a>
<a>T</a>
<a>U</a>
<a>V</a>
<a>W</a>
<a>X</a>
<a>Y</a>
<a>Z</a>
```

If you want all links within the `alphabetnav` and `alphabetNavMobile`, then just extract the function above as a named function and use the following selectors and call the function on both of the divs:

```
function addAndReplaceLinks(idx, a) { /* code from the anonymous function above */ }

// apply the function to both divs
$('.aphabetnav a').each(addAndReplaceLinks)         // select all links from the alphabetnav and do the replacements
$('.alphabetNavMobile a').each(addAndReplaceLinks); // select all links from the alphabetNavMobile and do the replacements
```

Comment: I would recommend $.trim($(a).text()) to avoid any spaces.

Comment: @nem What about those that have href previously and I want to replace the old href with span and  the new JSON letters with href

Comment: how can you replace an `href` with a `span`? Do you want to remove `href` for unmatched elements?

Comment: @nem yes remove href for unmatched elements for  alphabetNavMobile and alphabetNav to show link is disabled here my fiddle FIDDLE currently it returing duplicates  http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/ohbogqyw/3/

Comment: Wait, remove `href` or convert the `<a>` into a `span`? If you want to just remove `href` but keep it as a link, just add an `else` statement that calls `removeAttr`, as I've shown in my edit. Your fiddle has too much code to look at, it would be easier if you would tell me what you need.

Comment: @user244394 you can see in the attached snippet how it removes all href's from previous matched elements (A and B) and adds all the currently matched ones (G and F).

Comment: @nem href replacement also works for me  will this code work for both the  block "alphabetnav and alphabetNavMobile" as i have to update the

Comment: @nem I just tried your code it doesnt seem to work here is my fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/ohbogqyw/5/ Did i miss something?

Comment: @user244394 don't just give a fiddle, tell me what goes wrong, where to look in the code, don't just expect me to do everything :). The code i gave you here works, as demonstrated in the attached code snippet.

Comment: @nem I updated ur code with my array , so when I passed in the array  alphaArray.indexOf(testLetter) ..it didnt do anything  i was trying to show you in my fiddle line 327 to  line 338 as  this is limited here.

Comment: You mispelled `alphabetnav` as `aphabetnav` on line 327.